# node.js file upload Error: ENOENT, rename ' tmp/xxxxxx.jpeg', think the fault is in my path, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, dir

My code looks like this:

[image]

and the terminal output looks like this:
[image]

But I dont want the path to be under "routes". But rather under bears/public/...

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current setup, you're just joining the path as a string. This doesn't allow you to move up levels within your folder structure.

```
var path = require("path")

var target_path = path.join(__dirname, "../public/images/bjornar")
```

[The path module](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) will join them as if you were moving around in command line.

Comment: That helped with the path, many thanks!
Now I get a new error tho, will make a new question about it since it probably doesn't relate to path.

Comment: Was on this problem for 3 days... this saved me! Thank you so much dude!